# Como Cambiar Icono de mi Aplicacion en 2do Plano Plano en Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-rio

Supongamos que tengo una aplicación corriendo en segundo plano pero deseo que, cuando se cumplan ciertas condiciones, su icono cambie y se vea reflejado en el Administrador de Tareas, tal y como lo hace el *Windows Defender* y muchas otras aplicaciones.

He intentado Cambiar el Icono del Form y de la Aplicación, pero no surte efecto.
Ejemplo de lo que he intentado pero no funciona

```
ImageList1.GetIcon(0,Application.Icon);
ImageList1.GetIcon(0,Form1.Icon);
```

A esto me refiero:

[image: Esto es lo que quiero lograr]

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer no es cambiar el Icono de la aplicación, sino lo que [Windows llama "Icon Overlay"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-implement-icon-overlay-handlers), es decir, no se modifica el icono, sino que se superpone un determinado símbolo al icono existente de la aplicación.
Por ejemplo, es lo que hacen programas como TortoiseGit o TortoigeSVN para mostrar el estado de los ficheros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa el link anterior y verás los Interfaces que te dan acceso a programarlo.

Comment: Al parecer este método es usado en fichero y carpetas a nivel del shell de windows, si permite multiples representaciones de iconos superpuestos al original, pero solo a nivel del explirador de windows, no logro encontrar la manera de implementarlo en un proceso q está corriendo. Igualmente GrAcI@s.

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar el icono de la aplicación en tiempo de corrida, lo que debes hacer es cambiar el icono del formulario principal, a menos que la propiedad [`MainFormOnTaskBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainFormOnTaskBar) del objeto `Application` sea `False`, en cuyo caso hay que cambiar la propiedad [`Icon`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Icon) del propio objeto `Application`.

Un ejemplo sencillo sería el de tener varios iconos en archivos en el mismo directorio donde está el ejecutable, de acuerdo a un estado numérico:

```
Icono1.ico
Icono2.ico
...
Icono12.ico
```

Con lo cual el cambio podría ser algo como:

```
procedure TForm7.CambiarIcono(AEstado: Integer);
var
  NombreArchivo: string;
begin
  NombreArchivo := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\Icono' + IntToStr(AEstado) + '.ico';
  if FileExists(NombreArchivo) then
    if Application.MainFormOnTaskBar then
      Application.MainForm.Icon.LoadFromFile(NombreArchivo)
    else
      Application.Icon.LoadFromFile(NombreArchivo);
end;
```

También puedes tener los iconos almacenados como recursos dentro del propio ejecutable, lo cual resulta más recomendable.

Comment: Ok voy a probarlo y te digo que tal resulta, aunque no lo creo probable puesto que como dije, la aplicación corre en segundo plano por tanto la propiedad MainFormOnTaskBar es False, estube buscando información al respecto y al parecer Windows carga el icono solo a la hora de abrir el ejecutable, desde el recurso MainIcon 0 que es el q muestra en el administrador de tareas muestra cuando el proceso esta en 2do plano.

Comment: He logrado con el componente jvTryIco de JEDI-VCL pero causa un efecto no deseado, funciona solo mientras se muestra el icono en el area de lanzamiento de la barra de tareas y la idea es q no se vea allí, pero que si cambie en el administrador de tareas. Solo se que se puede hacer lo q al parecer conlleva algun pequeño truco que estamos pasando por alto

Comment: @Juan no estoy seguro de a qué le llamas "ejecutarse en segundo plano". ¿Es que la aplicación no tiene nada visible en la barra de tareas, ni ventanas?